# Azure Kinect with ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros-humble

I have been trying to configure my Azure Kinect to be used in ROS2 Humble but I haven't had success.
Here are a few links I found with good information

https://gist.github.com/madelinegannon/c212dbf24fc42c1f36776342754d81bc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software#ubuntu

Any help would be awesome!

Update (still not working)

Following the comments below (thank you)

1. Manually downloaded libsoudio and installed
2. Downloaded the k4a files and installed ([from here](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/1790#issuecomment-1181255655))
3. Made a ros workspace and cloned the Azure demo project
4. `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y`

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
azure_kinect_ros_driver: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [K4A]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

If I just ignore this a colcon build the package, this is the result:

```
Starting >>> azure_kinect_ros_driver
--- stderr: azure_kinect_ros_driver                              
Finding K4A SDK binaries
!!! Body Tracking SDK not found: body tracking features will not be available !!!
K4A Libs: k4a::k4a;k4a::k4arecord
K4A DLLs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk4a.so.1.4.1;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk4arecord.so.1.4.1
K4A Install Needed: FALSE
---
Finished <<< azure_kinect_ros_driver [6.39s]

Summary: 1 package finished [6.51s]
```

Doesn't seem a terrible output but it still doesn't work.

I also followed the instructions [here](https://scazlab.github.io/azure_setup_guide.html) and created the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-k4a.rules` file with the following content:

```
# Bus 002 Device 116: ID 045e:097a Microsoft Corp.  - Generic Superspeed USB Hub
# Bus 001 Device 015: ID 045e:097b Microsoft Corp.  - Generic USB Hub
# Bus 002 Device 118: ID 045e:097c Microsoft Corp.  - Azure Kinect Depth Camera
# Bus 002 Device 117: ID 045e:097d Microsoft Corp.  - Azure Kinect 4K Camera
# Bus 001 Device 016: ID 045e:097e Microsoft Corp.  - Azure Kinect Microphone Array

BUS!="usb", ACTION!="add", SUBSYSTEM!=="usb_device", GOTO="k4a_logic_rules_end"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="097a", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="097b", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="097c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="097d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="045e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="097e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

LABEL="k4a_logic_rules_end"
```

But k4aviewer gives me this error:

```
[ error    ] : usb_cmd_io(). Error calling libusb_bulk_transfer for initial tx, result:LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
[ error    ] : usb_cmd_io(usbcmd_handle, cmd, p_cmd_data, cmd_data_size, p_data, data_size, NULL, 0, bytes_read, &cmd_status) returned failure in usb_cmd_read()
[ error    ] : usb_cmd_read(depthmcu->usb_cmd, DEV_CMD_DEPTH_READ_PRODUCT_SN, NULL, 0, (uint8_t *)temp_serial_number, sizeof(temp_serial_number) - 1 , &bytes_read) returned failure in depthmcu_get_serialnum()
[ error    ] : depthmcu_get_serialnum(device->depthmcu, serial_number, &serial_number_size) != K4A_BUFFER_RESULT_SUCCEEDED returned failure in k4a_device_open()
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* guidout, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu 22.04.

Install the Azure Kinect Sensor SDK as per official documentation stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure_Kinect_ROS_Driver/blob/humble/docs/building.md)

Install `ros2-humble-desktop`

Setup your ros2 workspace

Download the humble branch of the official driver [from here](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure_Kinect_ROS_Driver/tree/humble) into the src folder of your workspace

Run rosdep `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y`

Build the workspace with `colcon build`

Source the workspace `source install/setup.bash`

Run the launch file `ros2 launch Azure_Kinect_ROS_Driver driver.launch.py`

Comment: JJrome thank you. See updated post.

Comment: @guidout I have updated my answer. It may be because you did not run rosdep install to install all the deps of the ros2 package. I also noticed that one of the core deps is the azure kinect sensor sdk. Which you must build and install manually.

Comment: Also please look at this comment on how to install the deps using debian pacakges https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/1790#issuecomment-1181255655

Comment: guys, thank you for the comments and sorry for the delay. Please see update. I think I'm much closer but still one last step missing

Comment: @guidout did you follow these instructions? https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/1263#issuecomment-710698591

And did you do the device setup as outlined here https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/docs/usage.md#linux-device-setup

It seems like the problem is coming from not properly building K4A. Perhaps the debs you installed are not for ubuntu 22.04 so you must install the from source.